# Scales in this Logarithmic plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have this graph

[image]

Which is `f[a]` with `a` range `{a,0.0001,1}` and an arbitrary initial condition `f[0.0001]==1]`

I want to transform this plot into `LogLogPlot` and show in the new log plot the gridlines, espically the first one at ~ 0.0024 which is not clear on the current plot scale.

So what I did is changing the range of `a` , such that {Log[a], Log[0.0001],Log$[1]$}, or `LogLogPlot` with  `{a,-9,0}` , but this gives errors :
`Limiting value $ I \pi$ + Log[9]……`

Any help to reproduce an appropriate `LogLogPlot` covers all the range of `a`.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code,not only the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the `GridLines` unchanged:

```
Plot[  7  10^6 Exp[-a 5], {a, 0, 1}, GridLines ->{{.0024, .6}, None}]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[   7  10^6  Exp[-a 5], {a, 0, 1},GridLines -> {{.0024, .6}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But let me get the scales on the Log `a` axis. Now the grid line at 0.6 becomes at 0.51, to get the value of `a`, as I know in the natural logarithmic plot, I take `Exp[0.51]` which is `1.665` not `0.6`!

Comment: Isn't   `Log[.6]==-.51` negative?